# when we scroll listview, runtime added button change position in android

Tags: android

This is my listadapter class

```
public class ListDemoAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private String[] name={"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh","ii","jj","kk"};
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ListDemoAdapter(Context ctx) {
        context=ctx;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(view==null)
        {
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            view=inflater.inflate( R.layout.listitem, null);
            holder.tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            holder.btn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
            holder.rl=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.runtimerl);          
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv.setText(name[position]);
        holder.btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) context);
        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv;
        private Button btn;
        private LinearLayout rl; 
    }

}
```

and when we click on button then runtime button will generate but when we scroll list view then runtime created button changed in another row
code is given below :

```
public class AndroidListDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private ListView list;
    public static int pos=0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(new ListDemoAdapter(this));

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.addbtn){
            View view=(View) v.getParent();
            LinearLayout rl=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.runtimerl);
            Button btn=new Button(this);
            btn.setText(""+pos);
            btn.setTag(btn+"pos");
            rl.addView(btn);
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please make code in the question is readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look `getView` doesn't guarantee the position , when you scroll through the Adapter. As new Views are initialized every time you scroll through the list that has been initialized with adapter.

So, What you have to do is play with the `getView` method.

- Get `onClickListener` on your `convertView` instance.
- Initialize a static variable not in the getView method but inside Adapter class.
- Now assign the **static variable**  the **position** of the adapter's `getView` method obviously inside the `onClick` method of the `convertView`'s `onClickListener`.
- Visible your button at the same place